# Facebook Share Graph API

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer

I have an image in my server. I have to allow users to share it on their facebook account. I have APP ID and secret key. It works too. But it doesn't take that image which I'm passing in the og:image meta tag. I can't understand where is I'm going wrong. If anyone know answer then please explain or suggest me link from where I can understand from beginning. Thank You. Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
    <title>Site Title</title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="My Site Title"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.abcxyz.com/folder1/folder2/page1.php"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://abcxyz.com/folder1/folder2/images/image1.jpg"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="My Site Name"/>
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="10342XXXXXXXXXX"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="Awesome web and graphic design."/>
</head>
<body>
    <?php $url = urlencode("http://www.abcxyz.com/folder1/folder2/page1.php/"); ?>
    <a id="button" onClick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[url]=<?php echo $url; ?>', 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=550,height=400');" target="_parent" href="javascript: void(0)">
    Share This
    </a> 
</body>
```

Comment: does the facebook debugger recognize it? You may need to re-scrape the page to get it to update the image and scrape info http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: example with rottentomatoes https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=www.rottentomatoes.com%2Fm%2Fmatrix%2F

Comment: this may be some help, minimum image size is 200x200 pixels http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31753741/custom-image-on-facebook-sharer/32285939#32285939